# Is PI control loops in a software good to be define under interrupts?

Tags: assembly, interrupt, software-design

I'm working on assembly language project using C166 compiler on ST10F269.

My project is a pulse generator controller for a power converter using IGBTs.

It has to control the output voltage and output current of the power converter using a PI controller.

The PI controller receives the error in voltage or current and controls the duty cycle.

Then, **where should I define the PI control strategy in my software**? In the **normal system function or under an interrupt routine**?

Thanks in advance!

NB: Please let me know if you cannot understand my query

Comment: There is not much "strategy" to it, the one thing that matters is the timing.  It needs to be as consistent as possible to keep the loop stable.  Any variation makes the effective values of the gain and integration constants variable.  So doing this in the interrupt handler of a periodic timer is important.  Ensure that the error and command signals are sampled at a comparable rate.

Comment: If timing is considered, defining under normal system function is more suitable right? I think interrupt execution requires more time rather than normal system functions. Please correct me if I'm wrong